# is there any compilers for eletron (web or windows)

Tags: compilation, electron-builder

i am using the [GDevelop](https://editor.gdevelop.io/) game engine, you can compile your games for any OS (in my case windows) for free twice a day, when i make my games i need to constantly test the build to see if it works properly. i have tried fallowing eletron and GDevelops tutorial to compile the app myself. i have tried so much and to no avail. is there a windows app or web app that i can give it the zip file and get an output EXE?

i have tried using linux and windows terminals for running the commands to comple (with the nessesary packages installed) and googling to find a compiler

Comment: Why do you need a compiler?  Genuine question; I know you think you need one, but what are you actually trying to accomplish?  Read https://xyproblem.info.

Comment: because i need to build my game multiple times and GDevelop only does It for free 2 times a day. and i cant get it to work through the terminal